# What is the importance of Peano categoricity?

Tags: peano-axioms, second-order-logic, reverse-math

We know that Dedekind in 1888 proved that second order peano arithmetic(PA2) is categorical. My question is, why is it important? Does it have any mathematical, philosophical or foundamental consequences?
i.e if PA2 wasn't categorical, what would we lose?!

I think one of the result of it is that second order theoris don't need to be complete; because:
By Godel's incompleteness, Let G be Godel's sentence which is true in N but is not provable by PA2.
Since N is the only model for PA2, PA2 satisfies G. But PA2 doesn't prove G.

But the question is,are Existence of categorical theoris essential for showing that second order theories don't need to be complete?

Isn't there any other way to show that?

If yes, two questions arises:

1. What is it?
2. Then what is the importance of categoricity?

If No, is there any justification?!

Comment: "I think one of the result of it is that second order theoris don't need to be complete; because: By Godel's incompleteness, Let G be Godel's sentence which is true in N but is not provable by PA2. Since N is the only model for PA2, PA2 satisfies G. But PA2 doesn't prove G." This paragraph is a bit confused. There isn't a good proof system for second-order logic so it's not clear what provability means in this context. In fact the categoricity of PA2 (+ Tarski's undefinability argument) says that the entailment relation for second-order sentences is not second-order definable over $\mathbb{N}$

Comment: and so there is simply no "Godel-style" analysis of PA2 possible in the first place. (I think you might be mixing up the completeness of a *theory* and the completeness of a *logic*; what you write can be turned into a proof that SOL has no good proof system.)

Comment: @NoahSchweber Thank you very much. Then can you tell me what is the importance of categoricity?! What is it's mathematical or philosophical consequences?